# Conditional Copying in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formula, copying

I have the following problem which I can't seem to solve.
I have an inventory workbook with an order number listed as columns and types of products listed as rows. Beneath the order number, I have also specified the Shipping date and name of the customer. 
I want to make an automated shipping note sheet which is linked to this inventory sheet.

Here I want to be able to specify the order number so that the corresponding column with the amounts of each product is returned to the shipping note sheet. I was thinking of the formula (in cell C6 which specifies the amount ordered of the first product) `=IF($B$4=Outbound!E$4$, Outbound!E7, 0)`

Here B4 is the input field for the order number, E4 is the order number cell for the first order (named for example A13001) and E7 is the corresponding amount of the first product from the first order in the Inventory sheet. When I copy this downwards it does return the amounts for the first order. However, what I want is when I change the order number input field (B4) into for example A13002, that the amounts of the products in the shipping note sheet change as well (so the second column of the inventory sheet instead of the first column corresponding to A13001). Which formula should I use and how?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your worksheet(s) or a link to your workbook.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lw42d5cnucd014s/86dc4jFqFp

Comment: Note that the cells in my question above don't correspond with the actual cells as i've altered the layout of the sheet a little bit. This doesn't change the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you'll need a combination of INDEX and MATCH. In cell C11 use the following formula, and copy down. If you change the order nr, the corresponding quantities will change accordingly.

```
=INDEX(Outbound!$A$1:$CN$97,MATCH(Pakbon!A11,Outbound!$A:$A,0),MATCH(Pakbon!B$8,Outbound!$1:$1,0))
```

INDEX returns a value at the intersection from a given column and row, in a given range

This is your range:

```
Outbound!$A$1:$CN$97
```

This returns the row number:

```
MATCH(Pakbon!A11,Outbound!$A:$A,0)
```

This returns the column number:

```
MATCH(Pakbon!B$8,Outbound!$1:$1,0)
```